# HTML & CSS Image transitions with link maps

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, anchor, transition

I'm making a language option so that when the user hovers over a globe, the flags of Norway and the USA pop up. Each flag will link to a page in the respective language. I'm using transitions so that the flags appear over the course of one second.

I did this by using two images; "top" contains the image of just the globe, and "bottom" contains the image of the globe and two flags by its side. On top:hover the opacity fades to 0, revealing the bottom image with the flags.

I've tried anchor elements with absolute positioning and I've also tried image mapping but the same problem persists... when I hover onto the link area, I am no longer hovered over "top," so the original image of only the globe fades back in. I need it so that as I'm hovered over the link areas, "top" still has an opacity of 0. I'm trying to avoid using javascript so if it can be done in just HTML & CSS, I'd prefer that. Is there any way to keep the opacity at 0 until I'm done hovering over both "top" and the link areas? Thanks.

```css
.languageExpand {
  position: absolute;
  right: -2%;
  bottom: 21px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.languageExpand img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /*FADE EFFECT*/
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.languageExpand img.top {
  z-index: 7;
}

.languageExpand img.bottom {
  z-index: 3;
}

.languageExpand img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.languageExpand img.bottom:hover {
  z-index: 5;
}

map {
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="languageExpand">
  <img class="top" src="Images/languageBegin.png" usemap="#langMap" />
  <img class="bottom" src="Images/language.png" />
  <map name="langMap">
    <area shape = "rect" coords = "35,45,75,85" href = "indexNO.html" alt = "Norsk lenke">
    <area shape = "rect" coords = "175, 45, 215, 85" href = "index.htm" alt = "English link">
    <area shape = "rect" coords = "100,39,149,87" href = "index.htm" alt = "English link">
  </map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the hover trigger work using your `.languageExpand` container instead of the `img.top`. Remove your css for `.languageExpand img.top:hover` and add:

```
.languageExpand:hover img.top {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then when the entire container is hovered over, the bottom image will always fade into view.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!!